# Is there any existing ebcdic file readers available as part of spring batch framework?

Tags: spring-batch

We are developing a batch job using ebcdic file(mainframe), I am just wondering is there any existing reader class available to read the ebcdic file?

Thanks,
MK

Comment: If one is identified, I'd love to see it contributed to the spring-batch-extensions repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions

Comment: starting point can be https://github.com/SonarSource/ebcdic-to-ascii-converter see https://github.com/SonarSource/ebcdic-to-ascii-converter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sonarsource/cobol/ebcdic/FileConverter.java

Comment: Thanks for your responses..I will use the above converter to build the reader..